How can i serialize a very large xml doc over 4000 pages using KendoUpdate for AngularJS?
I have an xml doc over 4000 pages in length  and i want to use
but this fails to load IN THE KendoUpload control
The error comes from the following in AngularJS
    $("#srcFile").kendoUpload({
                multiple: false,
                async: $scope.settings,
                files: $scope.initFile,
                 …..
            });

Can i configure the kendoupload control to use maxjsonlength ?
Or can i upload in batches /chunks ?
